# strange behaviour in asp-route-*

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

in the index.cshtml I use an anchor tag helper as

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-firstname="@Model.Name"</a>
```

and in the action method

```
public IActionResult Edit(string id, string firstname)
{
   // id and firstname are assigned correct values
   // but  RouteData.Values only has three entries which are: controller, action and id, where is firstname?
}
```

But I **cannot** access the firstname value via `RouteData.Values["firstname"];` and I can access  the id value  via `RouteData.Values["id"];`, how come it works for id but not for any other custom attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RouteData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routedata?view=aspnetcore-2.2) will only contain data that is relevant to *routing*. What data this is depends on the route template that is used to navigate to your action.

The default route template looks like this: `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`. Ignoring the default values, the template is just this: `{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

So there are *three* slots in the route template: `controller`, `action`, and an optional `id`. These are the values that you will be able to see in [`RouteData.Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routedata.values?view=aspnetcore-2.2) because those values were used to match the route template.

You can also see this when you look at the URL that gets generated by the tag helper. It should look somewhat like this: `/Home/Edit/123?firstname=name`. The `id` is part of the route, while the `firstname` is only passed as a query argument.

That also means that you *can* access `firstname` through [`HttpContext.Request.Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.query?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which contains the query arguments that were passed. Note that `id` is *not* included there though because it is passed as route data instead of as query data.

Now, when you use [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with your controller action, you luckily don’t need to make this distinction. The default behavior will allow you to get both route parameters and query parameters by simply specifying them as parameters to the action method. And using model binding is certainly the recommended way to access these values, making `RouteData.Values` and `Request.Query` rather low-level mechanisms.